# Ryzen 5900X CPU governors not available, and can't change

Tags: performance, cpu, amd-ryzen, governor

```
$ systemctl status cpufrequtils.service 
● cpufrequtils.service - LSB: set CPUFreq kernel parameters
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cpufrequtils; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2022-01-26 16:58:27 EST; 11h ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 76974)
     Memory: 0B
        CPU: 0
     CGroup: /system.slice/cpufrequtils.service

Jan 26 16:58:27 Y4M1-II systemd[1]: Starting LSB: set CPUFreq kernel parameters...
Jan 26 16:58:27 Y4M1-II cpufrequtils[1960]:  * CPUFreq Utilities: Setting ondemand CPUFreq governor...
Jan 26 16:58:27 Y4M1-II cpufrequtils[1960]:  * disabled, governor not available...
Jan 26 16:58:27 Y4M1-II cpufrequtils[1960]:    ...done.
Jan 26 16:58:27 Y4M1-II systemd[1]: Started LSB: set CPUFreq kernel parameters.

$ sudo cpufreq-set -g performance
Error setting new values. Common errors:
- Do you have proper administration rights? (super-user?)
- Is the governor you requested available and modprobed?
- Trying to set an invalid policy?
- Trying to set a specific frequency, but userspace governor is not available,
   for example because of hardware which cannot be set to a specific frequency
   or because the userspace governor isn't loaded?

$ sudo ls -la /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root    0 Jan 26 16:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 33 root root    0 Jan 26 16:58 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root    0 Jan 26 16:58 cache
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    0 Jan 27 04:16 cpuidle
-r--------  1 root root 4096 Jan 27 04:16 crash_notes
-r--------  1 root root 4096 Jan 27 04:16 crash_notes_size
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Jan 27 04:16 driver -> ../../../../bus/cpu/drivers/processor
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Jan 27 04:16 firmware_node -> ../../../LNXSYSTM:00/LNXCPU:00
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Jan 27 04:16 hotplug
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Jan 27 04:16 microcode
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Jan 27 04:16 node0 -> ../../node/node0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Jan 27 04:16 power
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Jan 26 16:58 subsystem -> ../../../../bus/cpu
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Jan 26 16:58 topology
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Jan 26 16:58 uevent
```

I don't know what changed, but I'm now suddenly unable to change the CPU governor on my Ryzen 5900X.

Which driver is supposed to be loaded?

Comment: I think the default CPU frequency scaling driver is acpi-cpufreq. I think no `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq` directory (link to `../cpufreq/policy0` actually) suggests a BIOS or kernel command line setting disabling frequency scaling.

Comment: Yeah.  I just figured out why.  I have to make sure "Cool & Quiet" is enabled.